# Why D7 Update Manager keeps sending emails?

Tags: updating

This is very weird,

http://example.com/admin/reports/updates/settings

keeps sending emails to my email while the owner of **example.com** has changed his website from **Drupal 7** to **weebly**! I mean, the Drupal installation does not exist!

Comment: This is not really related to Drupal; most probably the server where Drupal website was installed is still working and the cron is triggering those emails to be sent. Make sure those files are removed from the server / deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Manager is a module that exists and works inside your installation. This means that Drupal installation **exists**. Maybe it is no longer connected to domain, but it is there, up and running. Delete it and you'll be all right. Or, if you want to keep it for backup / rollback purposes, ask your sysadmin to delete it's CRON rule. Without system's cron and visitors, nothing will trigger update checks and mail sending.